# Cycle id from #nav links

Tags: html, cycle

i want to know the id names from links inside #nav div, i try to find what id have , but i dont find nothing about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath expression to get set containing all interesting nodes.

```
document.evaluate("//div[@id='nav']/a", document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null)
```

Code above will return set containing all **a** elements that are children of **div** element that has **nav** id.

Here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vycMP/3/

You can read more about XPath here: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in the browser, I suggest using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), then you can use a selector similar to CSS, which would make this quite easy.

```
$('#nav a').each(function(index) {
    alert($(this).attr('id');
}
```